# Apply a transformation on variables to get linear relationship

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Have a look at the plot below (let's assume the vertical axis is called 'y' and the horizontal axis is called 'x'). This is how my two variables are related. I was wondering whether it would be possible to apply a transformation on one of my variables in order to get a more linear relationship? I tried taking the log, but this still gives poor results. The (shortened) dataset looks like this

```
x    y
1    21.905933
2    12.341214
5    6.601826
10   4.687770
25   3.541561
50   3.224406
100  3.082521
250  2.999060
```

The goal is to create a linear model with y as dependent variable and x as independent variable.

[image]

Comment: What does this curve look like to you?  Also, is this an assignment?  If so, please add the self study tag.

Comment: log difference?

Comment: plot $\log(y-2.95)$ vs $\log(x)$   (or thereabouts) ... but note that this shift-value is effectively an estimated parameter

Comment: There are some good answers to similar questions [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/box-cox-like-transformation-for-independent-variables) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24227/how-to-choose-the-best-transformation-to-achieve-linearity).